# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Readability.js:108

Tags: javascript

I want to investigate the functionality of reader mode in Firefox for Android. To do that I took [Readability.js](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/242aa3916310/mobile/android/chrome/content/Readability.js) from Firefox sources and created a simple HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Readability.js"></script>
</body> </html>
```

If I load the above page in Chrome and open JavaScript Console I see

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Readability.js:108

If I do the same in Firefox, the result is similar:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @ file:///XXX/Readability.js:108

Why does Readability.js work in Firefox for Android and does not when used as shown above in desktop browsers?

Comment: Have you checked what’s on line 108?

Comment: 108: let scheme = this._uri.scheme;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other answers and comments I figured out that it is necessary to specify javascript version in the script element:

```
<script src="Readability.js" type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

The let keyword was added in version 1.7. After this modification, there are no javascript errors (tested under Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in the wild doesn't yet have the `let` keyword. It's something that [Mozilla's dialect has had for a while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), and [it's coming in ES6](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3alet), but you can't expect to find it in the wild yet.

Comment: However, the script uses `let` and `const` all over the code, so why does Chrome choke on that particular line (and not a previous one)?

Comment: @Bergi: It's a good point. Truthfully, I don't know. It does for me too, if I try including that file. But I think fundamentally, as we know Chrome's V8 doesn't support `let` without experimental flags set, and gives that error if you try to use it (http://jsbin.com/OwEHUJO/1), that's the issue.